# How to set "updatedBy" automatically in Mongoose model hooks

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Say we have a Mongoose schema hook like so:

```
someSchema.pre('save', function(next){
  this.updatedBy = // assign to the logged in user  <<<<
  this.updatedAt = new Date();
  next();
});
```

how can I pass the logged-in user information to this hook?

Seems very difficult to do, the way it is by default.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. You're breaking through layers of code. This hook has no business knowing the logged-in user. Instead, I recommend using a custom save method, such as `saveBy(modelInstance, user)`. I know it's not the most appealing syntax, but IMO, if you somehow get the current user to appear in this method, you'll create a ton of future headaches

Comment: I agree, would you mind adding an answer with a full code sample (will help other ppl, not just me), thx